# Macbook gets confused by switching external USB keyboard

Tags: keyboard, usb

I have two different locations to use my MacBook pro and attach an external USB keyboard at both places. They are both 104keys and have identical layouts.

When I first plug in the keyboard it often (not always) stops working properly. The modifier keys will be completely incorrect and then most of the regular keys are also translated improperly.

What I have been doing is mess around with the laptop builtin keyboard a bit then back and forth for a while (tens of seconds to a minute or so) before the keyboard functionality *usually* gets back to normal.

I have not been able to settle on a pattern that reliably works any better than the above - which is messy and moderately unpredictable.

Has anyone run into this and come up with a better solution?

*Answers to comments*

- rebooting does not have an effect: this behavior has been happening for months at least
- "identical place" not sure what that means but both USB ports have been tried numerous times and do not affect the result
- Modifier keys are  wacked out. It's not as simple as *Option and Command are swapped* : for example doing *Command-Tab* seems to go to *Expose'* .  There is *no* key combination that does the proper Application Switching.
- Regular keys are also wacked out.  Typing *asdfg* does weird things including jumping to different applications.  Behavior is too unexpected and extreme to decipher

Comment: If you reboot, does it function properly?

Comment: Are the keyboards at both locations identical?

Comment: I don't have that problem with two Bluetooth keyboards (of different manufacturers).

Comment: Can you give specifics about exactly how the modifier keys are not correct?  What happens when you type asdfg for example?

Comment: @TomGewecke added to question

Comment: What if you boot8 to Safe Mode (hold Shift while booting)?

Comment: @Allan  Not sure you saw this - the keyboard does start working properly .. _eventually_  (tens of seconds to couple of mins).   I don't think booting to safe mode every time I plug in the keyboard would be wise.

Comment: Repeatedly booting into safe mode wouldn't hurt anything, but would be clumsy. However, a safe boot does accomplish some under-the-hood repairs. Give it a try; perhaps something it'd touch would affect your keyboard misbehavior.

Comment: Safe mode is to see if the problem goes away - it’s for diagnostics, not a solution